# Which movie adaptation of "Flowers for Algernon" is the closest to the original story?

Tags: book-adaptation, flowers-for-algernon

After reading the [wonderful story](http://www.sdfo.org/gj/stories/flowersforalgernon.pdf), I've decided to reach for the movie adaptation. To my surprise, there are at least FOUR adaptations based either on the short story or the book:

- ["Charly"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062794/) (1968) - won Oscar for best leading actor
- "[Flowers for Algernon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0210044)" (2000) - straight to DVD movie
- "[Des fleurs pour Algernon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0885484)" (2006)
- "[Flowers for Algernon](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4428284)" (2015) - Japanese miniseries

I am not asking which version is the best, since this can be highly subjective, but which one is the closest to the original.

To precise what I'd consider a "faithfulness points":

- The story, besides the use of the "experimental surgery procedure" is not SF. I've noticed that few movies on IMDB are marked as Sci-Fi
- All the main plots from the book/story are in the adaptation (I've seen a theatrical version, where the romance  plot and the mouse plot were omitted).
- The original story is provided in the form of a diary ("Resurhc prgress repot")

Comment: Why downvote and close request? Asking about faithfulness to the original story is not subjective.

Comment: I don't consider closing *yet*. However, even that is still quite broad and dependent on how you even *define* "faithfulness" to begin with. Are you looking for plain plot faithfulness, faithfulness to the atmosphere (however you define *that* in turn), or to the characterizations and themes? How much faithfulness in one aspect of the story can be sacrificed for faithfulness in other regards? This question *has* potential (and similar things worked in the past, if I remember correctly), but maybe adding a little more context and fleshing it out more might convince the close-voters of that

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I've edited the question, hopefully that will clarify it a bit.